# How to resolve an error from passing a Future<dynamic> instance as a parameter?

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart

I get the error:

> ```
> I/flutter ( 4091): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Builder:
> I/flutter ( 4091): Class 'Future' has no instance method '[]'.
> I/flutter ( 4091): Receiver: Instance of 'Future'
> I/flutter ( 4091): Tried calling: []("main")
> ```

And trace it back to:

```
void updateUI(dynamic weatherData) {
    setState(() {
      if (weather Data==null) {
      //error checking code that's not called; weatherData object isn't null
      }

      temperature = weatherData['main']['temp'];
      weatherMessage = weather.getMessage(temperature);
      var condition = weatherData['weather'][0]['id'];
      weatherIcon = weather.getWeatherIcon(condition);
      cityName = weatherData['name'];
    });
  }
```

The variables are initialized elsewhere. The problem's linked to something I clearly don't understand about Flutter Futures and/or asynch programming. The `weatherData` object is a JSON string pulled down from the openWeatherMaps API. If I call `print(weatherData)` where it's created, I get the expected JSON string. If I call `print(weatherData)` in the method above I get `Instance of Future'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're passing in a future which needs to be resolved before you can use it.

```dart
void updateUI(Future<dynamic> weatherDataFuture) async {
  final weatherData = await weatherDataFuture;
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Your suggestion gets me an error saying `type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Map<String, dynamic>>'`

Comment: Ah sorry, change it to `Future<dynamic>`.

Comment: That did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The actual problem of this error is from the method where the data is fetched is not marked as await. For example

```
NetworkHelper networkHelper = new NetworkHelper(url);

var weatherData = await networkHelper.getData();
```

In the above, the networkHelper is marked as await.